# Can you create a uniqueness constraint for the relationship between all nodes that fall under two labels in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following labels:

- `(:Product)`
- `(:Brand)`

Their relationships is as follows:

- `(:Product)-[:is_of]->(:Brand)`

As an example, if the below query is run twice it will succeed.

```
CREATE (:Product { name: "Chocolate"})-[:is_of]->(:Brand {name: "Cadbury"})
```

And the graph result for the below query can be seen in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0TDe.png)

```
MATCH (p:Product { name: "Chocolate"})-[:is_of]->(b:Brand {name: "Cadbury"}) RETURN p,b
```

As you can see there is 2 "Chocolate" product nodes and 2 "Cadbury" brand nodes.

I would like to enforce that when creating a product there is only one product node with property `name = "Chocolate"` that has an `is_of` relationship with a brand with property `name = "Cadbury"`. So the above `CREATE` query would fail on the second attempt with some message like: `There is already one product node with a name = "Chocolate" and a brand of "Cadbury". This is prohibited by a constraint`.

The relational database analog would be a primary key that stretches over multiple foreign keys. For example, adding the below to table `Product` where table `Brand` has a primary key `Brand ID`:

```
PRIMARY KEY("Product ID","Brand ID")
```

I've tried placing a constraint on a property of the Brand to only allow unique brands. But the problem is you can still create two products that `is_of` the same brand. I don't want to create a unique constraint on product `name` as well because there can be multiple "Chocolate" products from different brands.

I've read through the documentation but it seems that constraints can only be placed on properties...

I would imagine syntax that would look something like below:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON g=(p:Product)-[:is_of]->(b:Brand) ASSERT g IS UNIQUE FOR p.name, b.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.

There has been talk about having arbitrary pattern syntax for constraints in Neo, but it's not there or on the roadmap as of yet, AFIAK. The closest I've found in the wild is in an unmerged CIP in an unofficial repo:
https://github.com/Mats-SX/openCypher/blob/88c0f11f11410ce2f68dc050e54ff419058c6cad/cip/1.accepted/CIP2016-12-14-Constraint-syntax.adoc

See documentation for current available constraint syntax:
https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/

The closest you can come in 3.3.x, I think, is converting that `:is_of` relationship to a node and putting properties on it that you can make a node key with.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also now convinced it is not possible. I've added a feature request to [Neo4j github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/11747). But, for now, it seems I won't be using it. This feature is pretty important for my requirements and I ain't hacking it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`. [The docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) about `MERGE` says:

> The MERGE clause ensures that a pattern exists in the graph. Either
>   the pattern already exists, or it needs to be created.

So running the following Cypher command twice

```
MERGE (:Product { name: "Chocolate"})-[:is_of]->(:Brand {name: "Cadbury"});
```

will produce the following graph:

[image: Result]

Comment: The thing with MERGE is that it doesn't prevent someone from entering bad data. It's not a constraint

Comment: @MarthinusEngelbrecht Yes, you are right. As you said, constraints can only be placed on constraints. My suggestion is handle this type of validation at application layer instead of database layer.

Comment: @BurnoPeres that might be the only option, but it's not preferred. Let's see maybe someone else can come with a pearl of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an update to this older thread as this comes up with constraint search results.

What you're trying to do requires an Enterprise license. You can enforce constraints on paths ()-[]-() when you have an enterprise license. You can also use scenarios with multiple attributes.

As an FYI, I would turn your arrows the other way as IMHO brands have a relationship (directed) to their products. It might enable the constraint to be enforced with the non-enterprise version a bit easier as well. Just a thought.